# How to timeout RabbitMQConsumer if it didn`t receive response

Tags: go, rabbitmq, timeout, channel

I got code that consumes messages from RabbitMQ queue. It should fail if it doesn`t received message for some time.

```
msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        c.ResponseQueue, // queue
        "",              // consumer
        false,           // auto-ack
        false,           // exclusive
        false,           // no-local
        false,           // no-wait
        nil,             // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

...

loop:
    for timeout := time.After(time.Second); ; {
        select {
        case <-timeout:
            log.Printf("Failed to receive response for action %+v\n Payload: %+v\nError: %+v\n", action, body, err)
            return errors.New("Failed to receive response for action")
        default:
            for d := range msgs {
                if corrID == d.CorrelationId {
                    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(uncompress(d.Body)), &v)
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }
                    ch.Ack(d.DeliveryTag, false)
                    break loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I took consume code from RabbitMQ manual and tried some advices for implementing timeout. I know how to do it in Java, but can`t repeat it in Golang.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Changed select to this:

```
c1 := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            if corrID == d.CorrelationId {
                err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(uncompress(d.Body)), &v)
                if err != nil {
                    c1 <- err
                }
                ch.Ack(d.DeliveryTag, false)
                c1 <- nil
            }
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-time.After(defaultTimeout * time.Second):
        log.Printf("Failed to receive response for action %+v\n Payload: %+v\nError: %+v\n", action, body, err)
        return errors.New("Failed to receive response in time for action")
    case err := <-c1:
        failOnError(err, "Failed to process response")
    }
    return err
```

Now it works as expected - if it doesn`t receive message with proper corellationId it will fail with timeout. Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: In java it's a property on the ConnectionFactory ? So you don't have to handle the condition in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop has a `select` with 2 cases: a timeout and a `default` branch. Upon entering the loop the timeout will not fire, so the `default` branch is executed.

The `default` branch contains a `for range` over the `msgs` channel which keeps receiving from the channel until it is closed (and all values have been received from it). Normally this shouldn't happen, so the timeout case will not be revisited (only if some error occurs and `msgs` is closed).

Instead inside the loop use a `select` with 2 cases, one timeout and one  that receives only a single value from `msgs`. If a message is received, restart the timeout. For a restartable timer use [`time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer).

```
timeout := time.Second
timer := time.NewTimer(timeout)
for {
    select {
    case <-timer.C:
        fmt.Println("timeout, returning")
        return
    case msg := <-msgs:
        fmt.Println("received message:", msg)
        // Reset timer: it must be stopped first
        // (and drain its channel if it reports false)
        if !timer.Stop() {
            <-timer.C
        }
        timer.Reset(timeout)
    }
}
```

Check this [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EwGJd1Pe2jK) example to see it in action.

Note that if you don't need to reset the timer once a message is received, just comment out the resetter code. Also, if no reset is needed, [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) is simpler:

```
timeout := time.After(time.Second)
for {
    select {
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Println("timeout, returning")
        return
    case msg := <-msgs:
        fmt.Println("received message:", msg, time.Now())
    }
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QrEUOGT_cAz).

One final note: if you would break from the loop before the timeout happens, the timer in the background would not be freed immediately (only when the timeout happens). If you need this operation frequently, you may use [`context.WithTimeout()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout) to obtain a [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) and a cancel function which you may call immediately before returning to free up the timer resource (preferably as deferred).

This is how it would look like:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
defer cancel()
for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("timeout, returning")
        return
    case msg := <-msgs:
        fmt.Println("received message:", msg, time.Now())
    }
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1G1ggWAn8iu).

Comment: Thanks, but I don`t need timeout refresh in case if I received message. Tried to apply your changes to my existing code and it helped (updated question). Thx!

Comment: @Qworel If you don't need a reset, comment out the resetting code :) But then you may use `time.After()` after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed select to this:

```
c1 := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            if corrID == d.CorrelationId {
                err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(uncompress(d.Body)), &v)
                if err != nil {
                    c1 <- err
                }
                ch.Ack(d.DeliveryTag, false)
                c1 <- nil
            }
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-time.After(defaultTimeout * time.Second):
        log.Printf("Failed to receive response for action %+v\n Payload: %+v\nError: %+v\n", action, body, err)
        return errors.New("Failed to receive response in time for action")
    case err := <-c1:
        failOnError(err, "Failed to process response")
    }
    return err
```

Comment: this seems plain wrong to me. if two instances of this code run, msgs will be unsync, and some workers will miss their correlation id. values pops only once out of msgs.

Comment: @mh-cbon in our implementation we have one queue per worker so that`s not an issue